# Multirow is cut off

Tags: tabularx, multirow

I do have to use `multirow` in one of my tables, but unfortunately I am unable to get it working. The text is cut off and not certered vertically.

What's wrong with my code?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \captionabove{Abstände der Nebenmaxima vom Hauptmaxima in den Beugungsbildern der Gitter A bis D}
        \label{tab:abstaende}
        \vspace{-10px}
        \rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c c c c c m{0px} }
            \toprule \rowcolor{white}
                \multirowcell{2}[0.5ex]{Ordnung des \\ Nebenmaximums}  &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{Abstände vom Hauptmaximum [\si{mm}]}     &\\ \rowcolor{white}
                &   Gitter A    &   Gitter B    &   Gitter C    &   Gitter D        &\\[6pt]
            \midrule    
            \num{1}     &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{3.8 \pm 1}        &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{3.9 \pm 1}    &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{5.6 \pm 1}    &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{5.8 \pm 1}    &\\

            \num{2}     &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{7.8 \pm 1}            &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{7.7 \pm 1}    &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{11.6 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{11.8 \pm 1}   &\\

            \num{3}     &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{11.4 \pm 1}           &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{11.6 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{17.3 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{17.5 \pm 1}   &\\

            \num{4}     &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{15.4 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{15.4 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{23.3 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{23.5 \pm 1}   &\\

            \num{5}     &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{19.1 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{19.3 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{28.8 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{29.0 \pm 1}   &\\

            \num{6}     &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{23.2 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{23.0 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{34.7 \pm 1}   &   \num[separate-uncertainty = true]{34.9 \pm 1}   &\\

            \bottomrule \rowcolor{white}
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Should be fixed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second line of the `\multirowcell` is overwritten by the row color. When useing `\multirow` with table colors, put the `\multirow` entry in the last row, with a negate `nrows` parameter, like this:

```
    \toprule \rowcolor{white}
        &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{Abstände vom Hauptmaximum [\si{mm}]}     &\\ \rowcolor{white}
      \multirowcell{-2}[0.5ex]{Ordnung des \\ Nebenmaximums}   &   Gitter A    &   Gitter B    &   Gitter C    &   Gitter D        &\\[6pt]
    \midrule
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a little reformatting. I was too slow...

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Abstände der Nebenmaxima vom Hauptmaxima in den Beugungsbildern der Gitter A bis D}
    \label{tab:abstaende}
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white} 
    \begin{tabular}{%
        S[table-format={1.0}] 
        S[table-format={2.1}, table-figures-uncertainty=1]
        S[table-format={2.1}, table-figures-uncertainty=1]
        S[table-format={2.1}, table-figures-uncertainty=1]
        S[table-format={2.1}, table-figures-uncertainty=1]
        }
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Abstände vom Hauptmaximum in \si{\milli\metre}} \\
        \multirow{-2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Ordnung des\\Nebenmaximums\end{tabular}} & {Gitter A} & {Gitter B} & {Gitter C} & {Gitter D} \\
        \midrule  
        1 & 3.8  \pm 1 & 3.9  \pm 1 & 5.6  \pm 1 & 5.8  \pm 1 \\
        2 & 7.8  \pm 1 & 7.7  \pm 1 & 11.6 \pm 1 & 11.8 \pm 1 \\
        3 & 11.4 \pm 1 & 11.6 \pm 1 & 17.3 \pm 1 & 17.5 \pm 1 \\
        4 & 15.4 \pm 1 & 15.4 \pm 1 & 23.3 \pm 1 & 23.5 \pm 1 \\
        5 & 19.1 \pm 1 & 19.3 \pm 1 & 28.8 \pm 1 & 29.0 \pm 1 \\
        6 & 23.2 \pm 1 & 23.0 \pm 1 & 34.7 \pm 1 & 34.9 \pm 1 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

**Edit:**
Combination of *Piet van Oostrum*, *LaRiFaRi* and mine first version of answer (it is on bottom of answer) gives even more concise code for above picture of table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\belowrulesep=0pt
\aboverulesep=0pt    
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}% new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \centering
\captionabove{Abstände der Nebenmaxima vom Hauptmaxima in den Beugungsbildern der Gitter A bis D}
    \label{tab:abstaende}
    \vspace{-10px}
    \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!10}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{    C 
                            *{4}{S[table-format=2.1 (2),% from LaRiFaRi 
                                   separate-uncertainty = true,  
                                   table-figures-uncertainty=1]}}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor{white} % next dour lines from Piet van Oostrum
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Abstände vom Hauptmaximum [\si{mm}]}     \\
    \rowcolor{white}
\multirow{-2}{=}{Ordnung des Nebenmaximums}
  & \mcx{Gitter A} & \mcx{Gitter B} & \mcx{Gitter C} & \mcx{Gitter D}  \\
    \midrule % table content from LaRiFaRi
1 & 3.8  \pm 1 & 3.9  \pm 1 & 5.6  \pm 1 & 5.8  \pm 1 \\
2 & 7.8  \pm 1 & 7.7  \pm 1 & 11.6 \pm 1 & 11.8 \pm 1 \\
3 & 11.4 \pm 1 & 11.6 \pm 1 & 17.3 \pm 1 & 17.5 \pm 1 \\
4 & 15.4 \pm 1 & 15.4 \pm 1 & 23.3 \pm 1 & 23.5 \pm 1 \\
5 & 19.1 \pm 1 & 19.3 \pm 1 & 28.8 \pm 1 & 29.0 \pm 1 \\
6 & 23.2 \pm 1 & 23.0 \pm 1 & 34.7 \pm 1 & 34.9 \pm 1 \\
     \bottomrule 
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In comparison to the first version of answer use of `\num` in table is replaced by `S` column type as suggested *LaRiFaRi*, row colors are used as suggested *Piet van Oostrum*, for equal width of table columns serve new command `\mcx`.

**The first version:**
Using `tabularx` at least one column had to be `X` type. For centering I define new column type `C` (see MWE below). The use of `num{...}` in the first column is not necessary, for others the set up is defined at loading `sinunitx` package

Also `multirow` and `rowcolors` doesn't work fine together. So I add to `rowcolor` command to each colored row. The `arraystretch` is increased, and for better looks of table the vertical space above and below rules from `booktabs` are set to zero.

Purpose the last column isn't clear. I delete it as surplus.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty = true]{siunitx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\belowrulesep=0pt
\aboverulesep=0pt

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}%[H]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
        \centering
\captionabove{Abstände der Nebenmaxima vom Hauptmaxima in den Beugungsbildern der Gitter A bis D}
        \label{tab:abstaende}
        \vspace{-10px}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ C C C C C}
    \toprule 
%    \rowcolor{white}
\multirow{2}{=}{Ordnung des \\ Nebenmaximums}
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{Abstände vom Hauptmaximum [\si{mm}]}     \\
    &   Gitter A    &   Gitter B    &   Gitter C    &   Gitter D    \\
    \midrule
\rowcolor{gray!10}
1   &   \num{3.8 \pm 1}        
        &   \num{3.9 \pm 1}
            &   \num{5.6 \pm 1}
                &   \num{5.8 \pm 1}    \\
2   &   \num{7.8 \pm 1}
        &   \num{7.7 \pm 1}
            &   \num{11.6 \pm 1}
                &   \num{11.8 \pm 1}   \\
\rowcolor{gray!10}
3   &   \num{11.4 \pm 1}
        &   \num{11.6 \pm 1}
            &   \num{17.3 \pm 1}
                &   \num{17.5 \pm 1}   \\
4   &   \num{15.4 \pm 1}
        &   \num{15.4 \pm 1}
            &   \num{23.3 \pm 1}
                &   \num{23.5 \pm 1}   \\
\rowcolor{gray!10}
5   &   \num{19.1 \pm 1}
        &   \num{19.3 \pm 1}
            &   \num{28.8 \pm 1}
                &   \num{29.0 \pm 1}   \\
6   &   \num{23.2 \pm 1}
        &   \num{23.0 \pm 1}
            &   \num{34.7 \pm 1}
                &   \num{34.9 \pm 1}   \\
    \bottomrule 
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put the `\multirow` on the last row, with a negative number of rows. I improved your table using the `S` column type from `siunitx`, and simplified its coding. No tabularx is required, as you don't use the `X` column type. I replaced it with a simple `tabular`, within `threeparttable`, so the caption has the width of the table. Last point: rules  from `booktabs` leave a thin white strip at the top and bottom of coloured cells, due to the padding around these rules  (`\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`). There are workarounds with `makecell`, which also has variable width rules without the padding, but I cheated, removing this padding where necessary.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs,  threeparttable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \sisetup{table-format=2.1 (2), table-number-alignment=center,  separate-uncertainty = true,  table-figures-uncertainty=1,  %
     table-align-uncertainty}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \captionabove{Abstände der Nebenmaxima vom Hauptmaxima in den Beugungsbildern der Gitter A bis D}
    \label{tab:abstaende}
    \vspace{-10px}
    \rowcolors{1}{white}{gray!10}
    \begin{tabular}{c*{4}{S} m{0px}}%
        \toprule
         & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Abstände vom Hauptmaximum [\si{mm}]} &\\
         \addlinespace
       \cellcolor{white}  \multirowcell{-2}{Ordnung des \\ Nebenmaximums} & {Gitter A} & {Gitter B} & {Gitter C} & {Gitter D} &\\[6pt]
        \noalign{\vspace{-\aboverulesep}}\midrule
        \num{1} & 3.8 (10) & 3.9  (10) & 5.6  (10) & 5.8  (10) &\\
        \num{2} & 7.8  (10) & 7.7  (10) & 11.6  (10) & 11.8  (10) &\\
        \num{3} & 11.4  (10) & 11.6  (10) & 17.3  (10) & 17.5  (10) &\\
        \num{4} & 15.4  (10) & 15.4  (10) & 23.3  (10) & 23.5  (10) &\\
        \num{5} & 19.1  (10) & 19.3  (10) & 28.8  (10) & 29.0  (10) &\\
        \num{6} & 23.2  (10) & 23.0  (10) & 34.7  (10) & 34.9  (10) &\\[-\aboverulesep]
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]